# How to get full url address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get full url, in ASp.NET MVC 4, for example user entered url:

```
http://localhost:5555/#globalName=MainLines&ItemId=5
```

And when I try to get this url in `Global.asax`, I get only `http://localhost:5555/`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's impossible. The part that is following the fragment (`#`) is **never** sent to the server in the HTTP request and the server has no way of retrieving it. Fragments can only be accessed by javascript. So if you want to retrieve this value on the server you will have to use javascript to read it and then store it in some hidden field or something so that it gets sent to the server.